# React Mui "Converting circular structure to JSON" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I'm having "Converting circular structure to JSON" error in my app. Couldn't find any solution. It happens when clicking any button (or any "clickable" element) from Mui. It happens not only with modal, but even if I create MuiButton element without any function calls on click. If I use standart  it works. I've found couple of tickets from people facing same or similar error, but still no solution. Please, share any ideas?

```
const Header = ()=>{
    const [isOpenAuth, setIsOpenAuth] = useState(false);
    const [isOpenRegister, setIsOpenRegister] = useState(false);
    return <div>
        <header className="header">
            <Wrapper>
                <img src={logo} className="logo" alt="logo" />
                
                {/*<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setIsOpenAuth(true)} className="header-controls">Войти</Button>*/}
                {/*<Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => setIsOpenRegister(true)} className="header-controls">Регистрация</Button>*/}
                <button onClick={() => setIsOpenAuth(true)}>Войти</button>
                <button onClick={() => setIsOpenRegister(true)}>Регистрация</button>
            </Wrapper>
        </header>

        <Modal handleClose={() => setIsOpenAuth(false)} isOpen={isOpenAuth}>
            <AuthModal/>
        </Modal>
        <Modal handleClose={() => setIsOpenRegister(false)} isOpen={isOpenRegister}>
            <RegisterModal/>
        </Modal>
    </div>
}
```

Here is the error text:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
--- property '__emotion_real' closes the circle

Comment: Is Modal from Mui?

Comment: If you are importing Modal from Mui, you should use onClose instead of handleClose.

Comment: @JasonMing No, it's not. Error is not about modal, as i noticed error happens event if button doesn't have onclick method.